# Can a field with DATE type have a DEFAULT value with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, date, default

I know that for a DATETIME column you can you CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but what about a DATE column? I don't need hours, minutes and seconds and while trying to set CURRENT_TIMSTAMP as default for I get an error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `date` or `time` type columns can be defined with a `default 0` but not a `curdate()` or `curtime()`.

As per documentation on [*Data Type Default Values*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
on update CURDATE();
```

Try this if it works

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` 
   CHANGE `tablename` `tablename`timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```