# SQL Syntax error when using sysdate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sysdate

so i'm having an issue using sysdate function as my default data value in MySQL. my code to create the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
odr_date DATE DEFAULT sysdate() NOT NULL
);
```

i get the error

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sysdate()
>   )' at line 4

Comment: You need this answer _https://stackoverflow.com/a/22198098/767881_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `sysdate()` try `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for mysql

reference: [Type date default sysdate in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985321/type-date-default-sysdate-in-mysql?rq=1)

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    odr_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: This now gives the error: [42000][1067] Invalid default value for 'odr_date'

Comment: use datatype as DATETIME instead of DATE

Comment: Switching from DATE to DATETIME fixed the issue, thanks!